# Mapsquest geocoding api

Tags: php, curl, encoding, mapquest

I am using maps quest geocoding api to search for zip codes via geocode address api. Request part looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

//    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$return = json_decode($return);
var_dump($return);
```

$return looks like this: 
    string(163) "������������,���������������������������������� ������.,17,"

I don't think this service understands my request because other fields in response are empty.

If I paste my request into browser everything works fine. My request looks like this: [https://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=API_KEY&location=Москва,Яковоапостольский%20пер.,17](https://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=API_KEY&location=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80.,17),

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Since the request works in a browser and the encoding is commented out, this seems like it could be an url encoding issue. I can't see the result string in my browser.